# c++ class why need main?

Tags: c++, class, program-entry-point

Hello I'm writing a little project in c++ where I would like to have some classes that does some work, I wrote the interfaces and the implementation of the classes.

The thing that surprises me is that I cannot have a simple class without a main(), I would like to have a class that once instantiated, It's methods can be called, do things, but I don't need (nor want) a main() in the class implementation.
Here's an example I have in my head of what I'd like to have:

file animal.h:

```
class animal
{
 public: 
   animal();
  ~animal();

 public:
   int method1(int arg1);

 private:
   int var1;
};
```

file animal.cpp:

```
#include "animal.h"

animal::animal(){...}
animal::~animal(){...}
int animal::method1(int arg1){return var1;}
}
```

And I would like to call the animal class form another file and have it work, something like this:
file app.cpp:

```
#include <neededlib>
#include "animal.h"

int main()
{
 animal dog;
 cout << dog.method1(42);
 return 0;
}
```

But compiler give me

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.3/../../../crt1.o: In function _start:

"(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main`"

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

for animal.cpp, but I don't need a main there, or do I need it?

Where Am I wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to post the actual message. Often the devil is in the details.

Comment: "Don't forget to delete dog; !"

There is no need for that because it isn't a pointer, actually, deleting dog should normally in this case result in an error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> but I don't need (nor want) a main() in the class implementation.

The function `main` is your entry-point. That is where execution begins. You need to have one and only one such function.

> But compiler give me "undefined reference to main" for animal.cpp, but I don't need a main there, or do I need it?

Now, your problem looks like you have not *linked* the compiled forms of `app.cpp` and `animal.cpp`.

> I'm not so strong in Makefiles, I used something like g++ animal.h -o animal and g++ animal.cpp but it gives me the error above

You don't compile headers.  So don't use: `g++ animal.h`

When you compiled the animal.cpp separately, g++ created an object file. You will also need to compile the `app.cpp` because you *do need* the `main`. Once you compile the `app.cpp` file you will have to link it with the `animal` object file created earlier. But if these did not get linked in,  specially, the file containing the `main` function you will hit the error you are getting now.

However, `g++` takes care of what I have described above. Try something like this:

```
g++ animal.cpp app.cpp -o test
```

This will create an executable called `test` and you can run your application using:

```
./test
```

Comment: I'm not so strong in Makefiles, I used something like g++ animal.h -o animal and g++ animal.cpp but it gives me the error above

Comment: That tells g++ to make animal.h into a complete executable called animal, and animal.cpp into a complete executable called a.out (default name), and does nothing with app.cpp. Ether use the makefile that Mehrdad posted, or compile all of your cpp files at once like dirkgently said.

Answer (score 6):

First, this is wrong: `animal dog = new animal();`

You either need

```
animal * dog = new animal();
cout << dog->method1(42);
delete animal;
```

or preferably just

```
animal dog;
```

Second, you need to link together the object files produced by compiling your two source .cpp files.

```
gcc -o animal animal.cpp app.cpp
```

should do the trick, if you're using gcc.

Answer (score 4):

You should either compile them together (in a single `g++` command) or compile both of them to object files (`g++ -c`) and then use `ld` to link the object files together.

Sample Makefile:

```
all: app.exe

app.exe: app.o animal.o
    g++ -o app.exe app.o animal.o

app.o: app.cpp
    g++ -c -o app.o app.cpp

animal.o: animal.cpp animal.h
    g++ -c -o animal.o animal.cpp
```

Comment: Your sample Makefile seems to be missing "-c".

Answer (score 1):

```
class animal
{
 public: 
   animal();
  ~animal();

 public:
   method1(int arg1);

 private:
   int var1;
};
```

Notice you didn't put a semi-colon at the end of the class declaration. C++ requires it and sometimes gives confusing/misleading error messages if you forget it.

Comment: Sorry I just make an error writing here, the semicolon is in its place in the code :D thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
 public:
   method1(int arg1);
```

You are missing the return type for method1. Did you mean something like

```
   int method1(int arg1);
```