# `undefined reference to `main` in Cpp class without main()

Tags: c++, g++

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663870/c-class-why-need-main) while trying to get an answer.  But it seems like the poster had multiple files and they were not getting linked, and hence the error.

But, why do I get this error when using a single file?

```
g++ myClass.cpp  
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And why is `main` necessary here at compile time (**from where does it find a mention of main in my code**) ? `main` is the starting point of code execution, but why does the compiler assume i need a `main` here. I can have it defined in some other file and use `gcc -o` to make an executable?

Or maybe I am missing something else  in the code which causes the error?

```
#include<iostream>
class myClass
{

public:
myClass()
{
    std::cout<<"Constructor";
}

~myClass()
{
    std::cout<<"Destructor";    
}

};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`main` is not necessary to compile a source file. It is necessary to link a program into an executable [1], because the program has to start somewhere.

You need to tell the compiler that "this is not the whole of my program, just compile, but don't link", using the '-c' option, so

```
g++ -c myClass.cpp
```

which will produce a `myClass.o` file that you can then use later, e.g.

```
g++ -o myprog myClass.o myOtherClass.o something_that_has_main.o -lsomelib
```

(Obviously, substitute names with whatever you have in your project)

[1] Assuming you use the regular linker scrips that come with the compiler. There are "ways around that too", but I think that's beyond this answer.

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to compile an executable, so a `main` function is expected. You should compile an object file by using the `-c` flag:

```
g++ -c myClass.cpp
```

While you are at it, I suggest adding warning flags `-Wall -Wextra` at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

You are building your source as an application. Add `-c` option to produce only object file:

```
g++ -c myClass.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile only?! use `-c` option

```
g++ -c file.cpp
```

otherwise the project needs a `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-c` flag to compile and only tell the compiler to generate an object file. You're telling the compiler to make an executable.