# C++ std::cin won't work out of main()

Tags: c++, cin

In the first block of code, the compiler gives no error. On the other hand, the second block of code gives the error `error: 'cin' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`.

First block of code:

```
#include <iostream>

int y;

int main(){
std::cout << "Enter something! \n";
std::cin >> y;
}
```

Second block of code:

```
 #include <iostream>

 int y;

 int main(){
 std::cout << "Enter something! \n";

 }

 std::cin >> y;
```

What causes such a behavior? And can I fix it?

If you need more details, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: What causes such behavior is that it's not valid C++ code.

Comment: You can only run code inside a function.  Outside a function all you can do is declare variables and create types.  So `std::cin >> y;` In the second block of code is illegal - the compiler's error says that it was expecting you to declare a variable and std::cin is not a type (which is true - it isn't)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, but I want to know why it is invalid C++ code.

Comment: Because it does not meet the specifications for the C++ language.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/663889/4859885

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks for your input! You could have put that as an answer...

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Thanks... Will look into it.

Comment: @BoeNoe The answer to almost every "why" question about whether something is valid or not is "because the Standard says so."  Did you want a link to the relevant paragraph in the Standard?

Comment: @BoeNoe  I don't feel that two sentences is a good answer so I made it a comment instead.  An answer would explain more deeply what is valid and what is not and probably have examples to back it up.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Oh, ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way C++ works, you can't have executable code outside of a function. When the first block compiles, the compiler looks at the program something like this:

1. Ok, time to start this program! Let's look in `main()`
2. Ok, print `"Enter something! \n"`
3. Now wait for user input and store it in `y`
4. Ok, `main()` is done now, and there aren't any other functions... Guess the program's over!
5. There's nothing outside `main()` to worry about, so I'm done.

The trouble with the second block is that the compiler only gets to step 2. Then it thinks something like:

3. Well, `main()` is done
4. Anything to pay attention to outside of `main()`?
5. Oh, this looks like a new type declaration. But it's not.
6. Throw an error!

If you're taking a class or teaching yourself C++, you'll come across structs and classes later in your study, and those will make this make a bit more sense. They're an example of the kind of syntax the compiler is *trying* to interpret this as.

Comment: Upvoted for great explanation!

Comment: Even when there are other functions than `main`, when `main` is over, the program terminates. 4) is wrong.

Comment: @alain fair enough, I know that's how it works. I also know that the compiler doesn't speak in casual English. Maybe a more correct version would be "4) No other function calls, 5) `main()` is over, so terminate". But I think I got the point across.

Comment: ..oh I think you refer to compilation, but then 3) is a bit misleading because it's not the compiler that waits. Just settle for either compilation or runtime ;-)

Comment: Yes, fair point as well. I aggregated compilation and runtime because the OP was having compiler problems. I know it's a bit misleading, but for the sake of explanation to a beginner I felt that it was probably worth it to slightly obscure the truth. If the OP really wants to know what's going on under the hood, I'm sure they can find out.

Comment: Uhh, obscuring the truth? But I get your point.

Comment: Hm, maybe not the best choice of words. Leaving out some of the details, perhaps?

Comment: @alain, Harper, actually depending on platform, program can have several entry points. e.g. if   it's both command line utility and a service module in Windows, it will have two function, main for the first case. main is _default_ entry point. The truth here is simple - no statements are allowed outside function bodies, only declarations and definitions

Comment: @Swift yes but that is a non-standard extension. The C++ standard only defines `main`. (And yes, the truth is simple, I would have accepted your answer instead of this one, of course)

Comment: I don't have full text, but as I always was told , standard doesn't specify what entry point is, but if main present, it is entry. On practice, quite a number of modern platforms do not use symbol main at all. Also before main, there are called functions that do initialization,. Where main was defined, that is POSIX, not C++ standard. And you can  declare an array called main in C and its content will be treated as code of entry subroutine. From what I know there are words: **It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main function.**

Comment: @Swift What I meant is: the standard talks about `main`, but not about `ServiceMain`. Didn't know the C main array thing, interesting. A close draft to C++14 is [N4140](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cplusplus/draft/master/papers/n4140.pdf) if you don't have it.

Comment: Not gonna lie this is the most interesting comment chain I've been a part of in a very long time...

Answer (score 2):

You fail at basic syntax of C \C++.

`std::cin >> y;` is a statement. Statement aren't allowed outside of function body, only declarations are. Compiler attempts to treat that line as declaration and first token in declaration is a type specifier. Hence you do get that error message.